# how to know process pid of bash function running as child?

Tags: bash, process

I am trying to know the pid of a function that was run as child process on a script

FUNCtstPsSelf.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "pid=$$;ppid=$PPID"
ps -p $$
function FUNCtstPsSelf() { 
    sleep 3;
    echo "$FUNCNAME:pid=$$;ppid=$PPID";
    ps -p $$ -o pid,ppid,command; 
}
FUNCtstPsSelf&
sleep 1;
```

but it can't find the pid!
what now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$BASHPID` instead of `$$`. One of the two occurrences of `$$` in the man page is to explain when it differs from `$BASHPID`, including "subshells that do not require bash to be re-initialized", which may include your background function processes?

Comment: worked, here a simple example `function FUNCtst() { echo "$$,$BASHPID"; };export -f FUNCtst;FUNCtst;FUNCtst&`, thx!